# file_get_contents() error: "Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 ModSecurity Action"

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get the value from this following JSON array in a PHP variable.

This is a var_dump of the array:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["row"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["u_fname"]=> string(6) "Ashish" } } }
```

This is my code of the page

```
<?php 

$contents = file_get_contents('http://localhost/skillbook/json.php');
$contents = utf8_encode($contents);
$results =var_dump(json_decode($contents)); 
?>
```

However when I tried to get a service from online the `file_get_contents` function is not working.

> file_get_contents(http://...@gmail.com&pass=12345): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 ModSecurity Action in C:\xampp\htdocs\skillbook\json1.php

Comment: What exectly you want to fetch from this array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://localhost/skillbook/json.php');
$contents = utf8_encode($contents);
$contents_array = json_decode($contents,1);

$foundvalue= $contents_array[0]["row"]["u_fname"];
echo $foundvalue;
```

OutPut : **Ashish**

Comment: He wanted the value in a PHP variable, so you'd want the last line to be: $foundvalue = $contents_array[0]["row"]["u_fname"];

Comment: Dear Deepak when i tried to get a service from online the file_get_contents function not working     ...the error comes like this                                                  file_get_contents(http://...@gmail.com&pass=12345): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 ModSecurity Action in C:\xampp\htdocs\skillbook\json1.php on line 9

Comment: Thanks Deepak Mankotia and David

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use foreach condition for json

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://localhost/skillbook/json.php'); 
$json = utf8_encode($json);
$data = json_decode($json,true);

// change the variable name to devices which is clearer.
$devices = $data['0'];
foreach ($devices as $device)
{
   echo $device["u_fname"];
}
```

Comment: thanks Dhaval Patel..This works very well.but when i use an online url ,the file_get_content does not work.the error comes like file_get_contents(http://...@gmail.com&pass=12345): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 ModSecurity Action in. plz help.

Comment: Check in your php.ini so allow_url_fopen is set to on

Comment: allow_url_fopen is Already On . and the problem is same in Online also.

Comment: please debug phpinfo()  and check json related services work or not